# Not allowed to load local resource in C#

Tags: c#, botframework

i am trying to access a csv file from shared folder from different machine. But getting `Not allowed to load local resource` while accessing the file.

```
var Card = new Card
{
    Text = "Click here to view report",
    Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.DownloadFile, 
        "Get-Report", value: @"file://machinename/new/test.csv") }
};

return Card.ToAttachment();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but sounds like you need to change something about the folder configuration - since it's shared, it could have settings that prohibit you from accessing it in the above manner.

Comment: It is kind of error message that Chrome produces.  The botframework emulator is built on top of Chromium, nice coincidence.

Comment: @thesystem I have changed the security settings and gave full permission to everyone. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Who/what runs your process?

Comment: Local or network files are not supported in this context.  You would have to host the file somewhere with an https:// url.

Answer (score 2):

> access a csv file from shared folder from different machine

I do a test with the following sample code using a Shared Network Folder, which do not work as expected. I suspect it does not support for accessing the files stored from Shared Network Folder.

```
Attachment attachment = new HeroCard
{
    Title = "Click here to view report",
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
    {
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.DownloadFile,
        "Get-Report", 
        value: @"file://MININT-5CDVIK1/aaron_share/textdata.csv")
    }
}.ToAttachment();
```

As JasonSowers mentioned in comment, you can host your files somewhere, such as [Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction), that can be accessed from anywhere in the world via HTTP or HTTPS.

Besdies, If you’d like to easily share a file system across multiple machines, you can choose [Azure File shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction).